# Code Read-Only vs Read-Write, not same result

Tags: database, excel, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm having this very strange problem.

```
conn.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl " & _
             "SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "].[temp$]"
```

When I run this code in read write, it works. When I run it while the file is read-only, the code crashes and gives me this error : "External table is not in the expected format".

My connection string is (MS Access DB) :

`conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=mypass;Persist Security Info=True"`

I don't know what else to say... it's unlike anything I've ever encountered. It's so weird for something to work perfectly in read-write and not read-only.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you saying its weird to not be able to write to a table in Read only ?

Comment: No. The database stays in RW. It's the Excel file from which the code comes from that's either RW or RO. But usually a code in either RW or RO is the same code...

Comment: Hmmmmm... I may be onto something. I've read about using [Excel 12.0 Macro;...] for .xlsm. So I went and tried replacing ThisWorkbook.FullName (which is a .xlsm) by a .xls source containing the same sheet with the same data. It worked. It still doesn't explain why it works in RW and not RO.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Turns out this code uses the original state of the workbook if the workbook is Read-Only (which makes sense).

```
conn.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl " & _
         "SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "].[temp$]"
```

And since I was using the workbook in Read-Only and making a new sheet to put my temp data in, the original state loaded by the Execute didn't contain the new sheet as it wasn't saved.

Making a new temp workbook and saving it, refering to this new file, doing the insert and deleting it afterward seems to be the best solution.